# Can a transparent pen body produce spectrum?If yes,why?

Tags: visible-light

When I placed a pen in the path of sunlight it produced a spectrum.Though it was weak yet the colours can be seen easily .

Comment: The same way a transparent prism does. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism

Answer (score 0):

White light is composed of all the colors of the spectrum, as you know already I'm sure. When it passes through any object / medium, it may undergo refraction, and the refractive index for each color is slightly different, so you get a spread out of the colors. As in the comments above, it's the same idea as a prism, but because the plastic of a pen is not as efficient as a glass prism at splitting up color, you get a muted version of the spectrum produced by a clear glass prism.

The page [Refractive Index](http://sciencelearn.org.nz/Contexts/Light-and-Sight/Science-Ideas-and-Concepts/Refraction-of-light) gives you a better idea of the effect, as well as the refractive index of transparent substance.